# How to log the below snap with filter without if else?

Tags: project-reactor

```java
public Mono<Response> createSomething(PostRequest request, Option option, SiteId siteId) {
    Predicate<DeliveryPromiseResponse> isSplitShipment = pudoDPEResponse -> pudoDPEResponse.getShipments().size() > 1;
    return Mono.just(request)
        .doFirst(() -> log.debug("Processing request for siteId :", request.getSiteId()))
        .flatMap(shipRequest -> converter.apply(shipRequest, siteId))
        .filter(dpeResponse -> {
          if (isSplitShipment.test(dpeResponse)) {
       log.info("Received Shipment response from DPE for siteId :", request.getSiteId());
            return false;
          }
          return true;
        })};
```

Answer (score 0):

Although there might be another ways to achieve this behavior, I would personally refactor in two steps:

**1. Extract filtering to separate step:**

```
.filter(dpeResponse -> !isSplitShipment.test(dpeResponse))
```

To improve readibility, I would personally extract it to method called something like `isNotSplitShipment`.

**2. Extract side effect (logging) to `doOnSuccess` method:**

```
.doOnSuccess(dpeResponse -> {
    if (dpeResponse == null)
      log.info("Received Shipment response from DPE for siteId :", request.getSiteId());
})
```

Of course, this one could be extracted to a separate method, as well.

All together, will look, as follows:

```
return Mono.just(request)
        .doFirst(() -> log.debug("Processing request for siteId :", request.getSiteId()))
        .flatMap(shipRequest -> converter.apply(shipRequest, siteId))
        .filter(dpeResponse -> !isSplitShipment.test(dpeResponse))
        .doOnSuccess(dpeResponse -> {
            if (dpeResponse == null)
              log.info("Received Shipment response from DPE for siteId :", request.getSiteId());
         });
```

This way, we avoid mixing filtering with logging. Moreover, return `false`/`true` are not required anymore.

Nevertheless, it's worth mentioning here, that the `doOnSuccess` should be used cautiously. It should not invoke another Mono/Fluxes as it will not propagate errors to the main sequence.